# Show data with hidden ID with android

Tags: android, json, hidden-field

I have JSONArray with several JSONObjects and each JSONObject contains Name and ID. How can I show only the name and leave the ID hidden. I need to be able to get the ID afterwards by knowing which row was pressed. I don't care how to show it, with list view, table, grid or whatever. This is how I get the data from the JSONArray:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ans.length(); i++) {
    int id = Integer.parseInt(ans.getJSONObject(i).getString("UserID"));
    String disName = ans.getJSONObject(i).getString("DisplayName");
    adapter.add(disName + " - " + id);
}
```

Thank you in advance

After the first answer I created a Class name DisNameID containing diaplyName and ID and the toString is return displayName. The listView on this activity is called "frndLst". This is the code that should fill the listview:

```
ListView lstFrnd = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.frndLst);
ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.XXX, listItems);
for (int i = 0; i < ans.length(); i++) {
    int id = integer.parseInt(ans.getJSONObject(i).getString("UserID"));
    String disName = ans.getJSONObject(i).getString("DisplayName");
    DisNameID dis = new DisNameID(disName, id);
    adapter.add(disName + " - " + id);
}
```

Now I have 2 new questions: How to change the adapter to hold my new class - DisNameID? What to write instead of the XXX on the new adapter constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Holder object, override `toString`:

```
class Holder {
    private String name;
    private String id;
    //getters and setters;
    public String toString(){ return name };
}
```

Then add such objects to your adapter. This way, the name will be displayed, but you can get Holder objects from your adapter using [this method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItem(int)) and use the id.

Comment: I changed my question according to your answer